# FInd broken relations in MySQL

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a question about relational databases. I know that when using this I should set my foreign keys properly but I didn't do that right away so now I have to clean up my messy database in order to remove entries with broken relations. My tables look a bit like this:

LINKS
|  id  |  url  |  other, irrelevant fields  |

LINK_USERS
|  id  |  link_id  |  other, irrelevant fields  |

It should be obvious that LINK_USERS has a relation with LINKS through the link_id field (which is the id of the entry in the LINKS table)

I've been messing around for a bit of time now and somehow I can't seem to select all rows from LINK_USERS that have no reference in LINKS.

I must add here that deleting should only have happened on the LINKS table. So what I would want from the query is to SELECT all rows FROM LINK_USERS WHERE link_id cannot be found in the LINKS table.

As you might have figured, I am no MySQL guru. If my question is vague let me know and I'll try to formulate it better.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your question is not vague at all; you can get what you want with very simple SQL (which looks very much like your English language description of what you're looking for):

```
 SELECT * FROM LINK_USERS WHERE link_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM LINKS);
```

Comment: Depending on how large the tables are might it be better to do a Left Join here?

Comment: Wow.. I think it's time I take a break. This solution is so simple I should've thought of this myself! Thanks a million

Comment: the tables aren't very large. About 60.000 rows in link_users and 34.000 in links

Comment: @Will: This is a one-time clean-up query, I think, so I would go with the clearer statement rather than trying to hand-optimize the query.  In any event, most databases will optimize the two versions out to the same internal execution plan (I know this wasn't true of MySQL in the past, don't know if it still has a problem with this kind of query).

Comment: @LarryLustig this indeed is meant to be run only once to delete the rows that are now useless. I should be able to change the SELECT * into a DELETE in order to make the delete happen right?

Comment: @donnywals yes however always do a select first to determine you're deleting exactly what you want.

Comment: @WillSampson hehe, yeah I've once deleted more then I wished for. Now I'm a bit paranoid about it so a select is the least I should do before deleting lots of rows

Comment: @LarryLustig The reason I bring up the size of the tables is I was doing this exact query with the NOT IN on a table with around 6 million records where the network was timing out after a certain period of time.  Performing a LEFT JOIN instead fixed this for me.

Comment: It's a pity MySQL can't handle that optimization properly.  In the case you describe, you'll have to use the LEFT JOIN to get the performance you need.

Comment: That query should be `(SELECT id FROM LINKS)` instead of `link_id` right?

Answer (score 13):

Here's the LEFT JOIN version:

```
SELECT *
FROM LINK_USERS
LEFT JOIN LINKS ON LINK_USERS.link_id = LINKS.link_id
WHERE LINKS.link_id IS NULL
```

It does the same thing, but it might be quicker on bigger tables. YMMV.

Comment: Not might, it will be quicker for sure. And the difference can be tremendous because of how inefficient is `IN [array]` scan. This is actually the only correct general solution.

Comment: It would seem correct if deleting a row from LINKS would set LINK_USERS.link_id to NULL, which won't happen for @donnywals

Comment: @januszm the where statement is checking if the foreign table is null, which will be true even if the field in the parent table is not null

Comment: It should be `LINKS.id`, not `LINKS.link_id`?